# Probability Intersections

Tags: probability, education

$A$ and $B$ are two events from certain probability space $\Omega$.

*Knowing that:*
$P(A)=0.6$,  $P(B)=0.7 $ and $P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B) = 0.2$

Determine $P(A\cap B)$

**It says in this sheet that the result is $0.55$.**

Studying on the internet said that when they're independent
$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B)$

which results in $0.42$. Which is wrong supposedly. When they're dependent it's
$P(A\cap B) = P(B|A)\times P(A) = P(B)\times P(A|B)$

What operation is $|$? $(B|A)$ - division?

I don't know if they're dependent or not but in a question below it states that "$A$ and $C$ are independent" (so if there's the need to say they're independent it means the others so far were dependent).

I'm asking for a fast answer with an explanation (reason why, formula) so I can apply it tomorrow in the exam.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

In general: $$P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$$

It follows directly from integrating both sides of the evident equation $$1_{A\cup B}+1_{A\cap B}=1_A+1_B$$ with respect to probability measure $P$.

Comment: So P(A∩B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∪B) (=) 0,6 + 0,7 - 1,3? (0) Looks wrong to me :p

Comment: $P(A\cup B)=1.3$? *that* looks wrong to me! From where did you get that? Probabilities do not exceed $1$.

Comment: After "knowing that:.." in your question I read $3$ equalities. If you combine those with the fourth in my answer then you will come to: $P(A\cap B)=0.55$ and $P(A\cup B)=0.75$. Btw, do not use comma's in decimal numbers here, but points.